# Bull - Reached the max retries per request limit

Tags: express, redis, cron, queue, bull

I am using npm bull to add my queue job to handle about sending mail for my project. It runs no problems for a long time, but recently, it shows this error:
**Error while handling task collect-metrics: Reached the max retries per request limit (which is 10). Refer to "maxRetriesPerRequest" option for details.** [error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUwT1.jpg)
And I checked in redis-cli: key *, it didn't show any key.
The bull module support @bull-monitor/express to monitor the job, but since the error shows, I couldn't access the monitor
[bull admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeTkL.jpg)
[here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXWLA.png)

Answer (score 6):

I faced this problem as well when I deployed my application to production. It turns out that Bull.js doesn't automatically allow a redis connection over TLS, especially the fact that the production environment is already running over TLS. So what fixed it for me was setting `tls` to `true`, and `enableTLSForSentinelMode` to `false` in the Redis options of my queue. Here's a sample code:

```
const myQueue = new Queue('my_queue', YOUR_REDIS_URL, {
  redis: { tls: true, enableTLSForSentinelMode: false },
  ...other queue options
})
```

Comment: For users of NestJS, be aware the difference in structure of `RedisOpts`. In Nest, you can pass the `tls` option can be included in the opts passed to the `forRoot` method. Here in Bull, if you add the `tls` option in the config object as the second argument, it will be ignored.

Comment: I'm trying to connect to a redis server on the cloud (render.com specifically) however my BullMQ module for Nest JS fails connection. Any idea what the correct configuration for it is? @MegaSpaceHamlet

Comment: @Rohan I have never used render.com before, so I don't know anything about that, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

**Bull can't find Redis to connect with.**
I'm was using bull in local environment and there is no problem, on the cloud the bull shows me the same error.

so in local environment it's connect to *127.0.0.1:6379*, but in cloud you don't have this port so you need to specific the redis's username, redis's password and redis's port.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by setting some configuration settings on the Queue object as such:

```
export const networkUnreadsQueue = new Queue(
    'Network Unreads Notifications',
    process.env.REDIS_URL,
    {
        redis: { maxRetriesPerRequest: null, enableReadyCheck: false },
    }
);
```

Alternatively it is possible to update to a newer version of bull-board if you're using that, as it made my application throw the same error.
You can see [the same issue being discussed on their github page](https://github.com/felixmosh/bull-board/issues/546), resulting in a PR for version `5.0.0` that fixes the issue (but has breaking changes in the API, on how imports are structured).

Answer (score -1):

You are able to set your limit, if you want for example without limits just set maxRetriesPerRequest: null. But maybe it is bad for performance and etc.